# yii2 routes thread action function to controller

Tags: yii2, routes

if I have url rules like this

```
<module>/<controller>/<action>
```

how i can extends  as controller?

real example
i want to make route like this:

```
hxxp://s*te.com/admin/company/user/create
hxxp://s*te.com/<module>/<controller>/<action>/???
```

if you see, 'user' is a action from 'company' controller
I want to make user become a controller, so 'create' will be an action function

is possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Are you using Advance Template? Do you have backend folder for admin routes?

Comment: Probably understand your problem, do you want User to correspond to Controller? But what do you want admin in the route to mean? The entrance to a site? Still a module?

Answer (score 0):

```
'<module:[\w\-]+>/<controller:[\w\-]+>/<user_id:\d+>/<action:[\w\-]+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<user_id>/<action>',

public function actionCreate($user_id = null){
//your statment here
}
```